# reloading uitableviews in a uinavigation controller hierarchy

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, reloaddata

I browsed through the site for awhile to find an answer to this question but I couldn't seem to figure it out, so if this is repetitive please excuse me.

I am creating an ios app which uses a uitableview with a uinavigation hierarchy. When a user clicks a button a tableview is pushed on the stack, data is parsed from an xml document on a webserver and then populated with data. When the user hits the back button you are directed back the main page. If the user then hits the button to go back to the previously mentioned table view, the data is not reparsed from the webserver. The values are simply reloaded from the previous parse. Is there a way to prevent this from happening because the app will allow other users to update the values in the table view.

Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: There is not enough data here to help you. Post some code... maybe the code that adds the view controller? Dunno.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of your parsing method, before your last closing curly brace throw in:

```
[yourTableName reloadData];
```

See if that helps out.  I had a similar issue and that fixed it for me.

Comment: Just checking to see if you found the answer to your question.